# Why use IF...ELSE if the IF statement ends the function?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

Is there a benefit to using if...else outside of readability?

For example, if I have a function:

```
function a(b){
  if(b=="c"){
    return true
  }else{
    return false
  }
}
```

Couldn't I condense it more like this:

```
function a(b){
  if(b=="c"){
    return true
  }
  return false
}
```

The return false doesn't fire, so long as b=="c", but it doesn't require an else statement.

I've come across this many times, and I always opt for the more condensed version (mostly to save from writing more).  For examples like these, is there a reason to include the else statement more than readability?

Comment: Personally I always use the second way. I find it more readable than the first. Other advantages don't spring to mind.

Comment: I've been working with a lot of python, and I'm finding myself doing if statements and returning values, without using else statements at all.  If the first if fires, then it doesn't check the rest, because the function has returned a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably omit the else statement in your case. JSLint is even throwing in error when using `else` after a `return`.

Try following code on [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com):

```
function test() {

    "use strict";
    var b;
    if(b === "c") {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's also an unintended error in your code: Expected exactly one space between 'if' and '('. `if(b === "c") {`

Answer (score 2):

Usually `else` after `return` is considered superfluous, however, when "yes" and "no" branches are similar in some sense, it's better to keep them on the same indentation level, for the sake of symmetry. Compare:

```
// confusing

if (spam.exists()) {
    $(box).content = "Spam already exists";
    $(button).disable();
    return failure;
}

$(box).content = "Added new spam";
$(button).enable();
return success;
```

and

```
// less confusing

if (spam.exists()) {
    $(box).content = "Spam already exists";
    $(button).disable();
    return failure;
} else {
    $(box).content = "Added new spam";
    $(button).enable();
    return success;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function a(b) { return b == "c";}
```

Later edit:

If you do have a "return" statement inside your "if", you can omit the "else" statement, because.

Comment: I realize it could be condensed further. My question is specifically why/if I should have an else statement.

Comment: This might be a shorter version of OP´s code snippet, but it does not answer his question.

Answer (score 1):

In the given example, there's no actual difference. I find it better to use return statements to filter out all incorrect input results or possible errors to save the function body from over-identation.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **no** if the conditional command is `return` or another way to stop function or script.

But if there is only one conditionnal command, than bracket `{}` are useless:

```
function a(b){
    if(b=="c") return true;
    return false;
}
```

and

```
function a(b){
    if(b=="c") return true
        else return false;
}
```

Do exactly the same work as your original post. The `else` statment are normaly used for that kind of tricks:

```
if (b=="c") z="match"
   else z="wrong";
```

notice that there is no semicolumn `;` after the `true` in second sample and after`"match"`.

Comment: If you call that "tricks", here is a better one for you: `var z = (b === "c") ? "match" : "wrong";`